# a modulo b = c , I have b and c , how can I find a?

Tags: math, modulo, mathematical-expressions

Is there any way to find the variable "a" where ( a modulo b = c ) and "b" and "c" are known ?

Comment: There are infinitely many possible `a`s for which `a%b==c`.

Answer (score 1):

No.

'a % b = c' can be interpreted as 'a / b = k + c/b' where k is any real number.

Rearranging that 'a = kb + c', where again k is any real number. So while we can find the set that 'a' belongs to, we do not know the original value of 'a'